# Magento 2: CronJob bug? MySQL is always running at 30% usage and many php processes are running

Tags: magento2, cron, magento2.2, crontab, magento-cron

I am running magento 2 (2.2.1) on nginx and enable the cronjob by default.

```
php bin/magento cron:install
```

I don't customize any configuration regarding schedule of cronjobs.

after running the machine a few days, i saw that mysql service is always nearly 30-40% usage and machine is running a lot of "php7.1" processes

i reboot the machine and the error is the same, right now there are only a "few" php7.1 processes but it continue to raise

[image]

I already checked the logs, no errors there or exceptions.

I only found an issue on m2 backend

[image]

this indexer is always not "up to date"

can you please give me a hint how i can fix this problem?

attached a screenshot from the crontab

[image]

Comment: thank you user5198077 - i solved this problem manual

but is there a way to use this command also on schedule? maybe every hour or something like that? are there bugfixes available from m2 side?

Comment: I've edited the answer. To run every hour, edit * * * * * to 0 * * * *  (or replace 0 with whatever minute you want). For permanent fix, have a look on the github issue below, it seems there is one pull-request that may fix it, but it is not done as of today: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/12497

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My best guess,

See [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201063/should-2-of-the-standard-cron-always-be-running/) at stackexchange and [this](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11002) at github. The issue somehow appears as some cronjobs aren't indicated as completed. It freaked me out for quite some time.

**The quick diagnosis** to see if you have the issue is to run below query and if it comes back with more than a 1200-1500 or so, you likely have the issue:

```
select count(*) from cron_schedule;
```

**The quick fix** is to delete most of the stuff that have status running in cron_schedule:

```
delete from cron_schedule where scheduled_at < date_sub(now(), interval 1 hour);
```

**To avoid recurrence, establish a cron-job that periodically deletes the stuck jobs**. Below job can be added in cron-tab. However, if you have it on a shared server, the MySQL password and username will be visible by other users running top -c and similar and it is not advisable, read more on [guidelines for password security](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-security-user.html).

```
* */8 * * * <path_to_mysql_binary_dir>/mysql -u<sql_user> -p'<sql_user_pass>' <database_name> -e "delete from cron_schedule where scheduled_at < date_sub(now(), interval 1 hour)";
```

Adjust the * * * * * to fit the frequency, I don't see the need to run it very often, as I still haven't faced the same issue again after months of doing the quick fix.

Comment: If you have [magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2) installed in production, then you could pipe the mysql query to `magerun db:console` to avoid having the MySQL credentials in your crontab. The magerun command will get the credentials out of your `env.php`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a module to fix this issue:

https://github.com/magemojo/m2-ce-cron